# Description Resource Path Location Type Downloading external resources is disabled. pom.xml /ContactManager line 3 Language Servers

Tags: spring-boot

in my pom file an error showing like this how to solve this
my error is like
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'project'.  pom.xml /ContactManager line 2  Language Servers
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Downloading external resources is disabled. pom.xml /ContactManager line 3  Language Servers

these two errors have been shown from the starting of the creation of that spring boot file
how to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

Change from http to https. It helped in my case

Comment: this should be a comment and not the answer. answer is not clear and if possible, provide sufficient supporting information or some code examples

Comment: change WHAT to https?